# API key embedded in clients: how to defend against over-usage?

Tags: key-management, attack-prevention, api

I am new to client-side development and I have a naive question. Right now, I'm using Google APIs (the map ones). If I want my client-side application / webapp to display a map, I would include something like this in my `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
```

The API key in this snippet would have only the required permissions (let's say "get the map"). Even though the permissions of the key are restricted, it's still readable by an attacker. And every "get the map" action costs a bit of money.

How would I prevent an attacker from using this key to make millions of requests and drying my bank account?

Comment: Instead of making your app a wrapper for the Google API, why not send requests to your service?

Comment: I could indeed, but then that's 2 extra hops before my users get the data, and that's an extra load on my service. I was basically asking what's the standard practice in the industry. Everybody must have done that at some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, secrets should never lie unprotected on client-side indeed. But you have few options here:

- Expose the api key but take safeguards and apply restrictions (allowed origins, platforms, usage/budget cap, rate-limiting, etc). Cf. [Google: Restrict API keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key), [Google: API Security best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices) and [How do I securely use Google API Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625587/how-do-i-securely-use-google-api-keys)
- If your use case allows it and assuming you can have some server-side code running (i.e. using Node.js), use Google static maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview

**UPDATE**

- after reviewing the latest [TOS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) of Google and their [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#tos) it appears that the second proposal ("served static maps") could not be allowed by Google. Make sure you respect all terms and conditions (general and API-specific), including no caching, no storing.. of Google Maps Content. It does not seem though that Google specifically enforces and requires the use of static maps in embedded src links for this case (anymore). Please double-check as needed.